# hibernate: not cascade updates down to the child layer if the parent was new

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class with a hibernate mapping like this:
  
    
      
        
      
      
    
    ...

Basically I propagate a new (or old) tape with some StreamRef's, then hit

```
 session.saveOrUpdate(tapeInstance);
```

in case the tape is old or new.  The streamrefs that I add will all be new (but if I retrieve a tape from the DB, I want to be able to have easy access to its streamrefs).

Unfortunately, it seems I can't be "as lazy" as I want--the behavior that I would want would be, basically "if the tape is new, then that implies all of its streams are new, so never check to see if you can do an update on them, always just insert them", however "if the tape is old, update it, remove its old streamrefs, and then add the new ones to it--they'll always be new/unique, so just add them"  so basically, *don't* cascade the update through, but do cascade the saves through.  Is this possible?

I have worked around the problem by setting cascade="merge, delete, lock, refresh, evict, replicate, delete-orphan" (basically, it lacks save-update), then manually deleting all old streams, then manually adding each stream in, one at a time. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

By having cascade="AllDeleteOrphan", insertion and deletion is possible via list. To avoid updating, we need to properly specify an unsaved value for the primary key. NHibernate will then use the value of the primary key to determine if it's a new instance or an existing one. Note: By using "AllDeleteOrphan" cascade option, if a tapeInstance is deleted, all associated streamref's get deleted.